# storing date in 'CCYYMMDD' format in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I would like to store dates in the format `CCYYMMDD` in Teradata, but I fail to do so. Find below what I tried so far:

**query 1:**

```sql
SEL CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8))
-- Output: 20191230  ==> this works!
```

**query 2:**

```sql
SEL CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'CCYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8))
-- output: SELECT Failed.  [3530] Invalid FORMAT string 'CCYYMMDD'.
```

It seems that the `CCYYMMDD` is not available in Teradata right away. Is there a workaround?

Tool used: Teradata SQL assistant

Comment: It looks like `CC` refers to the first two digits of the year (i.e. 20 in 2019 or 19 in 1998).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420395/what-does-ccyymmdd-date-format-mean?rq=1.  So `CCYY` should be equivalent to `YYYY`

Comment: Thanks for the response @ravioli. The business requirement is to store the century number in place of 'CC'. e.g 2019-12-30 should be stored as '21191230'.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, dates are stored as integers in Teradata.  So when you say you want to store them in a different format, I don't think you can do that.  But you can choose how to display / return the values.

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to get the format you want, but here's one way:

```sql
WITH cte (mydate) AS (
  SELECT CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS CHAR(8)) AS mydate
)
SELECT 
  CAST(
    (CAST(SUBSTRING(mydate FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) + 1) -- generate "century" value
    AS CHAR(2) -- cast value as string
  ) || SUBSTRING(mydate FROM 3) AS new_date -- add remaining portion of date string
FROM cte
```

[SQL Fiddle - Postgres](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/44134)

You'd have to add some extra logic to handle years before 1000 and after 9999.  I don't have a TD system to test, but give it a try and let me know.